# Lua: Redirect extern function definitions to a specified table

Tags: c++, lua

I have one file "example.lua":

```
local function manipulate(something)
    return string.rep(something, 3) -- repeats the given string
end
function apiFunction(somethingelse)
    return manipulate(somethingelse)
end
```

and another files (main.lua) task is to "load"/"do" it:

```
loadAPI("example.lua", "externAPI") --< the part i need help with
externAPI.apiFunction("Test") --> should return TestTestTest
```

the thing that should happen is, that example.lua gets executed just like

```
dofile("example.lua")
```

but everything globally "defined" within example.lua (in this case the apiFunction) moves to the new generated global "externAPI" table and the rest (ie. manipulate) is hidden and only available from inside the example.lua file.
I've seen this bahaviour before in the minecraft mod "ComputerCraft" in which there is a function called "os.loadAPI("/somepath/sha-2") and it would define the definitions in the sha-2-chunk in the due to the name specified "sha-2"-table.

I've been searching for this sort of scoping/redirecting stuff for a while but there are no solutions putting the stuff into the new table.

I've been thinking of parsing the _G table after new indexes and move those to the new table but I'm sure there are some lua-magicians out here that know a much cleaner, better working solution to this.

All this is in one C lua_state* , so if there are any solutions adding this loadAPI function in C/C++ and just registrating it at the state this would be fine, too.

I've also looked at "require", but didn't seem to understand whether it does what I need.

Using Lua 5.2.3

Hope i didn't forget anything.
Thanks in advance :)

~InDieTasten

Comment: I'd really recommend not doing it this way. If you can do `local externAPI = {}; function externAPI.stuff() ... end; ...; return externAPI` along with require, it'd be in-line with Lua standards.

Comment: Ehmm... I'm sorry, but I don't quite get how I'm supposed to do that. A bit more example code would help me I guess.

Comment: `require` will load a file, execute it, and save the result. By returning a table at the end of your API's .lua file, require will return that, so you can do this: `local myAPI = require 'myAPI'`, instead of just `require 'myAPI'`, and magically having myAPI being defined. There's code samples and explanations in more detail here: http://lua-users.org/wiki/ModulesTutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function loadAPI(f,g)
    _G[g]=setmetatable({},{__index=_G})
    loadfile(f,"bt",_G[g])()
end

loadAPI("example.lua", "externAPI")
print(externAPI.apiFunction("Test"))
```